# Is it possible to replace javascript require with ES6 import using a regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am currently converting some javascript modularised using [require](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#require-amd-version) functions to [ES6 import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) statements.

For example, I want to convert

```
var dom = require("./lib/dom");
var event = require("./event");
```

to the following -

```
import * as dom from "./lib/dom.js";
import * as event from "./event.js";
```

I tried using a positive lookahead to match the variable names (`dom` and `event`)

```
\w+(?=\s+=\s+require\()
```

However when I used match substitution to build the `import` statement, it  includes the text following the variable names -

```
import * from $&
```

becomes -

```
var import * from dom = require("./lib/dom");
var import * from event = require("./event");
```

Can this be done with a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)? If so, how?

Comment: Normally you can use couple of helper CLI to convert cjs to esm

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible with a regex but it should complex if it's possible. `var dom = require("./lib/dom");` can occur almost anywhere in a code but `import * as dom from "./lib/dom.js";` can't. The regex has to check the current context.

Comment: @tmhao2005 I already tried a couple of tools such as [cjs-to-es6](https://github.com/nolanlawson/cjs-to-es6) but they fail in certain cases possibly due to face that the [original code](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/tree/v1.4.12/src-noconflict) is modularised using the [AMD Simplified CommonJS wrapping](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD#simplified-commonjs-wrapping-). I would prefer to interactively check each substitution.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a solution -

```
//require('req_name')"
file_in.contents = file_in.contents.replace(new RegExp(/\nrequire\("(?<req_path>.*\/)(?<req_name>.*)"\)/, "g"), '\nimport * as $<req_name> from "$<req_path>$<req_name>.js"');

//var var_name = require('module_name').member"
file_in.contents = file_in.contents.replace(new RegExp(/\nvar\s+(?<var_name>\w+)\s*=\s*require\("(?<module_name>.*)"\)\.(?<member_name>\w+)/, "g"), '\nimport { $<member_name> as $<var_name> } from "$<module_name>.js"');

//var var_name = require('module_name')
file_in.contents = file_in.contents.replace(new RegExp(/\nvar\s+(?<var_name>\w+)\s*=\s*require\("(?<module_name>.*)"\)/, "g"), '\nimport * as $<var_name> from "$<module_name>.js"');
```

file_contents before -

```
require("ace/lib/fixoldbrowsers");
var mockdom = require("../test/mockdom");
var AsyncTest = require("asyncjs").test;
var async = require("asyncjs");
```

file_contents after-

```
import * as fixoldbrowsers from "ace/lib/fixoldbrowsers.js";
import * as mockdom from "../test/mockdom.js";
import { test as AsyncTest } from "asyncjs.js";
import * as async from "asyncjs.js";
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var replaceRequireWithES6 = (fileContent) => {
  const requireRegExp = /(var|let|const)\s+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\s*=\s*require\s*\(\s*['"]([^'"]+)['"]\s*\)/g;
  const requireRegExp2 = /(import)\s+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\s*=\s*require\s*\(\s*['"]([^'"]+)['"]\s*\)/g;
  let match;
  let match2;
  let newFileContent = fileContent;
  while (match = requireRegExp.exec(newFileContent)) {
    newFileContent = newFileContent.replace(match[0], `import ${match[2]} from "${match[3]}";`);
  }
  while (match2 = requireRegExp2.exec(newFileContent)) {
    newFileContent = newFileContent.replace(match2[0], `import ${match2[2]} from "${match2[3]}";`);
  }
  return newFileContent;
}

var fileContent = `var dom = require("./lib/dom");\nvar event = require("./event");`

console.log(replaceRequireWithES6(fileContent))
```

Comment: How does your code check if the `require` is inside a function? `function f() { const a = require('something'); }` is valid. `function f() { import a from "something"; }` is not valid. The same is true for multiple other contexts.